# Entity Framework 6 - Map only one statement to Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am mapping an entity to insert to stored procedure like this:

```
modelBuilder  
  .Entity<Member>()  
  .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>  
       s.Insert(u => u.HasName("stp_insert_member")));
```

The insert works great and passes all parameters to the stored procedure when I save new member.

But what happens when I try to update a member (loading entity from db by id, changing it's properties, and saving again - what will issue the update statement) is I get an exception because it's looking for stored procedure named `Member_Update`.

But for that (and for delete), I don't want to have stored procedures. I just want to execute a stored procedure for the insert statement.

Can I map EF to a stored procedure for just the insert action?

Comment: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=code%20first%20insert%2Fupdate%2Fdelete%20stored%20procedure%20mapping

Comment: @GertArnold so in other words - not possible?

Comment: Not much room for interpretation there :). I'd just create sp's for add and delete as well.

Comment: @GertArnold not such elegant solution. In such case it sounds more like it's better to use micro-orm

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it's all or nothing.

[Entity Framework - Documentation](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=code%20first%20insert%2Fupdate%2Fdelete%20stored%20procedure%20mapping):

> You cannot use a mixture of stored procedures and direct table access for a given entity (or entity hierarchy). The insert, update and delete operations must all use direct table access or stored procedures.